# Derived from a positive self-adjoint operator.

Tags: functional-analysis

I am doing a job, which is to calculate the energy of a partial differential equation.
To do I calculate the following: Let $A$ be a positive definite self-adjoint linear operator on a real Hilber space $H$ and $ \mu $ a differentiable function, then I spend some internal products to derivatives. However I have a question to the following domestic product $ <A \mu, \mu> $, what I did was

$$<A \mu, \mu_{tt}> = \frac{d}{dt}<A\mu,\mu_{t}>  - <A\mu_{t},\mu_{t}> = \frac{d}{dt}<A\mu,\mu> - ||A^{1/2}\mu_{t}||^2 $$
But I'm assuming that $ \frac{d}{dt} A \mu = A\mu_{t} $  and my question is if it is okay, if any property that ensures that derivative.

Any help is grateful and sorry for my English.

Comment: There should be the same number of differentiations in each term so that each term has the same dimensions, eg. $time^{-2}$ in $$\frac{d}{dt}<A\mu,\mu_{t}> = <A\mu_{t},\mu_{t}> + <A \mu, \mu_{tt}>$$

Comment: corrected, however you assume $\frac{d}{dt}A(u)=A(u_{t})$? there are a proof of this?. Thx anyway

Comment: It's obvious from the definition of derivative.

Comment: Because you're probably dealing with a discontinuous linear operator $A$, there would be no reason to assume that $t\mapsto A\mu$ is continuous, or that $\frac{d}{dt}\mu \in \mathcal{D}(A)$.

Comment: yes, that's the problem, in this case A is a positive self-adjoint operator in a Hilbert space $ H $ with a dense domain $ D (A) \subset H $ This will ensure that the derivative exists?